# C# socket, ожидание поступления данных

Tags: c#, сокет

На socket устанавливаю соединение с удаленным оборудованием, черещ Send и Receive отправляю и получаю информацию, но при запросе определенной информации ответ приходит не полный.
Как поставить socket.Receve на прослушку по таймауту, пока не получились все данные?

Comment: Наверняка ваш код содержит ошибки. Никаких таймаутов не нужно, нужно знать размер пакета. Какой протокол используется для передачи данных? Как формируются заголовки пакетов, как вы их читаете? Пока вопросов больше, чем ответов. Хотя, ответ кроется именно в использовании готовой реализации нужного протокола, а не каких-либо костылей с таймаутами. Дополните вопрос, его можно редактировать.

Answer (score 0):

Вытащил кусок кода из моего сервера. Сначала, мы получаем тип очереди проекта. Для определения его важности. Это послужит нам выполнить данные сразу или поставить в очередь, пока до него дойдет серверный тик и выполнит его. Дальше из буфера мы читаем 2 байта - это будет длина нашего пакета, в типе `short`. Дальше выделяем память под оставшиеся входящие данные и через цикл while с учетом отступа 3 байтов дочитываем оставшиеся байты из потока. В моем случаи, преобразую в структуру `Packet`, где я выделяю те данные пакета, которые нужны. И в зависимости от типа очереди выполняю дальше согласно сервисам opcode.

```
public enum PacketImportance : byte
{
    None,
    Importance
}

private async Task ReadAsync()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeof(byte)];
            int bytesRead = await ClientNetworkStream?.ReadAsync(buffer, offset: 0, buffer.Length);
            PacketImportance packetImportance = (PacketImportance)buffer[0];

            buffer = new byte[sizeof(short)];
            bytesRead = await ClientNetworkStream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset: 0, buffer.Length);

            if (bytesRead == 0 || bytesRead != sizeof(short))
                throw null;

            short packetLenght = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, startIndex: 0);
            buffer = new byte[packetLenght - (sizeof(short) + sizeof(byte))];

            int countPackets = 0;
            while (countPackets < (packetLenght - (sizeof(short) + sizeof(byte))))
            {
                bytesRead = await ClientNetworkStream.ReadAsync
                    (buffer, countPackets, buffer.Length - countPackets);
                countPackets += bytesRead;
            }

            if (countPackets != packetLenght - (sizeof(short) + sizeof(byte)))
                throw null;

            if (packetImportance == PacketImportance.None)
                ClientPacketProcessor.AddQueue(buffer.BuildBufferToPacket(extraBytes: 0), this);
            else
                ClientPacketProcessor.AddQueueOutOfTurn(buffer.BuildBufferToPacket(extraBytes: 0), this);
        }
        catch
        {
            if (IsDisconnected)
                return;

            Termination();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 65535 - это `ushort`, а не `short`. И кто вам сказал про _максимальный обьем отправки данных_, вообще через установленное соединение сколько угодно можно данных передавать.

Comment: @aepot Протоколы транспортного уровня (протоколы TCP или UDP), пользующиеся сетевым уровнем для отправки пакетов, считают, что максимальный размер поля данных IP-пакета равен 65535, и поэтому могут передать ему сообщение такой длины для транспортировки через интерсеть.

Comment: Но при чем тут IP пакет, если у вас поверх него TCP? У вас в коде NetworkStream, пишите в него, читайте сколько влезет, TCP сам разобьет это на IP пакеты нужного размера и отправит. Бить что-то на куски на уровне приложения тогда,к огда это прекрасно может сделать протокол - мало смысла.

Comment: @aepot ну уберите давайте while цикл чтение данных, и передайте к примеру 100 Мб. Ничего не получится.

Comment: Конечно не получится, потому что нет гарантии, что вы получите все что надо за один Read. Поэтому надо контролировать количество полученных байт за одно чтение, у вас правильно написан код. Я про другое, про то что общий размер TCP пакета по факту не ограничен 64 килобайтами, это направда. Вы используете TCP, а говорите про ограничения IP, перепутали протоколы.

Comment: @aepot ааа, верно)